# Moving a Sprite Class from outside of the original Class in pygame

Tags: pygame

Currently I am making a small game in pygame, I was wondering if there is a way to move the class from outside of the original class function. Currently it looks like:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = Playerimg
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(Playerimg,(42,42))
        self.startposx = 298
        self.startposy = 358
        self.rect.x = self.startposx
        self.rect.y = self.startposy
    def update(self):
        ..... etc
```

Is there a way of making it so that you can change the value of self.rect.x and self.rect.y from outside the function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Once you created an instance of your class, e.g.:

```
player = Player()
```

you can simply access it fields, like

```
player.rect.x = 14
```

or

```
player.rect.move_ip(20, 3)
```

Comment: Thank You very much, didn't realise it was so simple.